# why command update in " insert or update " are working not right?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO `Users`
                (ID,FirstName,LastName) 
                    VALUE 
                ('60','Alex','Mathew') 
                ON DUPLICATE KEY 
                UPDATE 
                    FirstName = 'Alex' AND LastName = 'Mathew'

ID - is the Unique key
```

Insert works, but update sets `FirstName` to '0'. Where is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Test it:*

```
INSERT INTO `Users`
                (ID,FirstName,LastName) 
                    VALUE 
                ('60','Alex','Mathew') 
                ON DUPLICATE KEY 
                UPDATE 
                    FirstName = 'Alex', LastName = 'Mathew'
```

Change `AND` on ','

Comment: I suspect the reason this works is that in OP's form, the expression looks to MySQL like `FirstName = ('Alex' AND LastName = 'Mathew')`, assigning the value of the expression `'Alex' AND LastName = 'Mathew'` to FirstName.

Comment: @ctrahey may be... My tests show that in OP mysqli right will be use `,` instead `AND`.